# dc.js Row Chart values correct but bars all same length

Tags: dc.js

i'm trying to build a row Chart with dc.js. 
The keys / values for my dimension and group are correct (and displayed correctly in label and tooltip),
but the row bars are not rendered to their corresponding length, example :

```
var qyChart  = dc.rowChart("#top-ten") ;
qyChart
.dimension(qyDim)
.group(qyT)     
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))
.label(function(d){
        return d.key + " : " + d.value + " - " +(d.value / ndx.groupAll().reduceCount().value() * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
    })
.elasticX(true) 
.ordering(function(d){ return -d.value; })
.rowsCap(10)
.colors(qyColors)
;
```

Result :
[image: Resulting Graph]

Comment: (note that i masked the label data in red, it's not part of the rendering)

Comment: That's odd. Kind of hard to tell what's going on without seeing the rest of your code or a running example. Is it possible that your group values are strings instead of numbers?

Comment: thanks for your help, i'll check about that, but i think if it was the case my percent values would be also incorrect or NaN.

Comment: Javascript will coerce strings to numbers for `/` `-` `*` but not `+`

Comment: Update : problem was somehow in the dc.css, as i added some custom stuff inside. Switching back to original solved it, although i can't really figure out (even after a diff on files) what change caused that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh wow that is weird. Yes css has higher precedence than svg attributes so that explains it. Thanks for following up, it may help others in the future.